# dynamic created SELECT not passing correct VALUE to php

Tags: php, jquery

I have a select that is dynamically created.

```
<select name="approve-<?php echo $leadID; ?>" id="<?php echo $leadID; ?>" class="approve">
<option value="1">Yes</option>
<option value="2">No</option>
</select>
```

it is inside a php loop that retrieves records from a db. and a form that sends its content via $.post to a php file. for some reason even if I change the value of a SELECT, I receive back from the PHP file all 3 values the same. Any ideas?

JS:

```
var post = $('#approveLead').serialize();    
$.post("db/approveleads.php", post, function(data) { 
alert(data);
return false;   
});
```

PHP:

```
echo '<br/>'.$_POST['approve-1'];
echo '<br/>'.$_POST['approve-2'];
echo '<br/>'.$_POST['approve-3'];
```

Comment: have you examined the contents of `$('#approveLead').serialize()` before the data is sent to your PHP app?

Comment: @user998378: To help improve your question, please provide more details on the exact situation.  For example, include an example of your full generated form code, the output of `$('#approveLead').serialize()`, etc.  Currently, we can only shoot in the dark and your question is so specific that it won't help other users.

Answer (score 0):

As far I can understand your `$leadID` returns 1,2,3.... etc.... If this is true you may find the following helpful....

```
<select name="approve-<?php echo $leadID; ?>" id="id_<?php echo $leadID; ?>" class="approve">
```